# Issue in detacting event of listview row

Tags: android, listview, gesture, ontouchlistener

I have  try to create listview like iphone where if you swipe let/right it will show you delete button and if you click on row it ll goes to next activity
but i am facing some issue
I have issue in detecting event of list view row lick is clicked or is swipe

my code is

```
gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private int padding = 0;
        private int initialx = 0;
        private int currentx = 0;
        private  adapHolder viewHolder;
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                padding = 0;
                initialx = (int) event.getX();
                currentx = (int) event.getX();
                viewHolder = ((adapHolder) v.getTag());
            }
            if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {
                currentx = (int) event.getX();
                padding = currentx - initialx;
                if(viewHolder != null)
                {
                    if(Math.abs(padding)>HORIZONTAL_MIN_DISTANCE){
                        viewHolder.btnDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        viewHolder.imgArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        v.setPadding(padding, 0,0, 0);
                        //return true;
                    }
                }

            }

            if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
            {
                padding = 0;
                initialx = 0;
                currentx = 0;
                v.setPadding(10, 0,0, 0);
            }


             return true;

        }};
```

and my list view click event,

```
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View rowView, int positon,long id) {

                System.out.println("position :"+positon);

            }
        });
```

i have setted touch listener with each row in getview method

```
 convertView.setOnTouchListener(this.listener);
```

My listview click event is not fire, how i can manage both event

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to calculate time of motion(between start of motion and finish). If `timeOfMotion<delta` = `click`. If `time>delta` = another event. Remains to choose correct delta. Hope it's help.

Comment: thank you, can u pest some code here, i am confusing in return true/false, when and what i should return

Comment: sorry, I haven't a sample. You need get current timestamp when 'event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN' '(1)', then get current timestamp when 'event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL' '(2)'. Then  'timeOfMotion = (2)-(1)'.